# S3 always returns error code: NoSuchKey even with incorrect Bucket Name instead of some specific error code detailing about bucket

Tags: aws-java-sdk

S3 always returns error code: NoSuchKey i.e. 
"when bucket name given in request is incorrect"
       or 
"when bucket name given in request is correct but with invalid object key"

Is there any way so that S3 API start returning me some specific error code stating that Bucket do not exist instead of generic error: NoSuchKey in a scenario where invalid bucketname is passed while requesting object.

Comment: Please include code you're using as a starting point. E.g., S3 returns error code `NoSuchKey` in the following code...

Comment: @zanerock: amazonS3Client.getObject("invalidBucketName", "validKey")    It is returning me "NoSuchKey". Is there some way I can get more specific error code i.e. like InvalidBucket?

Comment: I was expecting error code like : "NoSuchBucket"

Comment: Did you add ListBucket permission in your IAM user or IAM Role?

Comment: Use the s3Client putObject method where it takes the PutObjectRequest with the bucket and the key seperately. I think you are directly sending the whole s3 Url as an input. So that might say the url or key is invalid. Try using the PutObjectRequest. Then it will specifically say if the bucket is wrong or the key is wrong

Answer (score 0):

First, check S3 object URL and the requested object URL is the same. Then check S3 upload handle properly asynchronously.
There can be a GetObject request that happened before the upload is completed.